# How to tell what version of Angular Classy you're using?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a minified `angular-class.min.js` file with no comments. Short of doing a diff against the various versions, is there a way to easily tell what version of [Angular Classy](http://davej.github.io/angular-classy/) is being used? Something that can be run in the console would be preferable (something equivalent to `jQuery.fn.jquery` would be perfect).

Comment: I haven't found anything in sources. So I can suggest only creating `angular.constant` with proper version inside your angular app.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see anything in the source either. But perhaps there might be some code that does feature detection to determine version #?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added this in [v1.2.3](https://github.com/davej/angular-classy/releases/tag/v1.2.3). Unfortunately there's no way to do this before that version.